# How to generate a secure id for a session at least 256 bits long using Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

Tarantool must return a string of 256 bits for example:
40ee6e5a8195284884215c2fcd476a4e4ad9a65adde8eea3efcc15b93fb44d65

Answer (score 3):

Built-in module [digest](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/digest/) can be used for this task. See an example:

```lua
tarantool> dg = require'digest'
---
...
tarantool> string.hex(dg.urandom(32))
---
- 3eeed423dd94abddbdeb0a27fea8f4926d77b75bb22f90b8cbb11530323c6d23
...
```

Of course, it's better to pass some unique meaningful information related to the session or a unique identifier -- `uuid` module or `digest.urandom` can be used for this. Be sure that the generated hash is **unique enough** and **cannot be brute-forced** within the session lifetime -- see, for example, [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24852) for an explanation.

The `digest` module also contains several variants of SHA lengths and their counterparts returning hex strings:

```lua
tarantool> dg.sha224_hex(dg.urandom(256))
---
- 6a8aa191d30f068a97c31a8c826d1b3e74d9890d57b8cbb7e2c65ca1
...
```